# Git archive line endings different from clone

Tags: linux, windows, git, newline, core.autocrlf

There are so many questions and topics about `CRLF`/`LF` conversion in `git`.

But, I cannot find the one focusing on the `archive` command.

In my test, `clone` works ok from windows and linux, but `archive` always returns `LF` in text files.

I want to use the `git archive` command on linux to download only part of a repository, to prepare a final release zip file... that will be used on windows after.

So how to FORCE `CRLF` for text files when using the `git archive` command?

Failed attempt:

```
git -c core.autocrlf=true -c core.eol=crlf archive ...
```

btw, there is no `.gitattributes` file existing or involved.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is supposed to work because I remember that there used to be a bug where it didn't work for zip archives [which was fixed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b99b5b40cffb5269e4aa38b6b60391b55039e27d).

Comment: @CharlesBailey not sure what is a problem, but i can not get crlf on 3 different machines and git versions (debian, arch and windows7) ... all of them shows LF only, for format=tar and for zip. (and win7 clone OK-crlf)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider

```
git -c core.autocrlf=false archive
```

This does not force `CRLF` line endings as such, *but* should preserve the same line endings that would occur when cloning the repository.

Additional discussion: https://groups.google.com/g/msysgit/c/dhac-Mc1-vM/m/bSC6CJZ4xm8J